# Need to add pwdlastset to this working powershell script

Tags: powershell

This script was written by someone else and is completely beyond me, I would like to also get pwdlastset added to the output.

```
    $NumDays = 90
$LogDir = ".\HaveNotLoggedInFor90Days.csv"

$currentDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
$currentDateUtc = $currentDate.ToUniversalTime()
$lltstamplimit = $currentDateUtc.AddDays(- $NumDays)
$lltIntLimit = $lltstampLimit.ToFileTime()
$adobjroot = [adsi]''
$objstalesearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($adobjroot)
$objstalesearcher.filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(lastLogonTimeStamp<=" + $lltIntLimit + "))"

$users = $objstalesearcher.findall() | select `
@{e={$_.properties.cn};n='Display Name'},`
@{e={$_.properties.samaccountname};n='Username'},`
@{e={[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc([int64]$_.properties.lastlogontimestamp[0])};n='Last Logon'},`
@{e={[string]$adspath=$_.properties.adspath;$account=[ADSI]$adspath;$account.psbase.invokeget('AccountDisabled')};n='Account Is Disabled'}

$users | Export-CSV -NoType $LogDir
```

Comment: Cool. What is it you need help with exactly, which parts are "beyond" you?

Comment: then select the property `pwdlastset`.

Comment: toni gave the reply below which added the line: @{e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.properties.pwdlastset[0])};n='Password last set'}
but that's not producing output, just getting a reply from PS Name                           Value
----                           -----
n                              Password last set
e                              [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.properties.pwdlastset[0])

Comment: got it needed to add ,` to the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$NumDays = 90
$LogDir = ".\HaveNotLoggedInFor90Days.csv"

$currentDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
$currentDateUtc = $currentDate.ToUniversalTime()
$lltstamplimit = $currentDateUtc.AddDays(- $NumDays)
$lltIntLimit = $lltstampLimit.ToFileTime()
$adobjroot = [adsi]''
$objstalesearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($adobjroot)
$objstalesearcher.filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(lastLogonTimeStamp<=" + $lltIntLimit + "))"

$users = $objstalesearcher.findall() | select `
@{e={$_.properties.cn};n='Display Name'},`
@{e={$_.properties.samaccountname};n='Username'},`
@{e={[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc([int64]$_.properties.lastlogontimestamp[0])};n='Last Logon'},`
@{e={[string]$adspath=$_.properties.adspath;$account=[ADSI]$adspath;$account.psbase.invokeget('AccountDisabled')};n='Account Is Disabled'},
@{e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.properties.pwdlastset[0])};n='Password last set'}

$users | Export-CSV -NoType $LogDir
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I run it all I get is: PS C:\Scripts> .\Get-LastLogonMoreThan90Days.ps1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
n                              Password last set
e                              [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.properties.pwdlastset[0])

Comment: fixed it, needed to add ,` to the line

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thats is what I get and you should get the same :-) To simplify the code you could also use the PowerShell cmdlets for ActiveDirectory (RSAT):

```
$NumDays = 90
$currentDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
$currentDateUtc = $currentDate.ToUniversalTime()
$lltstamplimit = $currentDateUtc.AddDays(- $NumDays)
$lltIntLimit = $lltstampLimit.ToFileTime()

$users = @(get-aduser -ldapfilter "(lastLogonTimeStamp<=$lltIntLimit)" -Properties passwordlastset,enabled,lastlogontimestamp,displayname)
$usersOutput = @(
    foreach ($u in $users){
        $attrsHt = @{
            DisplayName=$u.DisplayName
            UserName=$u.samaccountname
            LastLogon=[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc($u.lastlogontimestamp)
            Enabled=$u.enabled
            PasswordLastSet=$u.passwordlastset
        }
        new-object -typename psobject -property $attrsht
    }
)

$usersOutput | export-csv -Delimiter ";" -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding:utf8 -Path '.\HaveNotLoggedInFor90Days.csv'
```